# Why Floating Point Division is not Precise in Computers?

Tags: floating-point, division, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, fpu

There is lots of explanations and resources in internet. some of them is mumbo-jumbo, some of them is somewhat clear saying that it's because of FPU works differently and e.t.c. but no clear and short answer is shown though..
can anybody explain in a popular language terms Why and How Division operation is not giving accurate and precise result when it comes to Float numbers?

Comment: Is the suggested [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) unsatisfactory for some reason?

Comment: Long story short - it works fine, but peoples *decimal* expectations don't match the *binary* reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division is one of IEEE 754 basic operations for which the result is, in the default rounding mode, the **nearest** representable floating-point number to the real result. [Here](http://www.bt.pa.msu.edu/TM11/talks/revol1.pdf) is one deck of slides, of which “IEEE-754: specification of the arithmetic operations” lists division as one of the operations having this property.

What other result would you expect for floating-point division that would be more accurate?